# Loading an array of objects using Java Serialization

Tags: java, serialization

The following code is two methods, one for saving to a file using object serialization and one for loading and deserializing the saved file for the user to read:

```
private void SaveDeck() throws Exception {
    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
    FileOutputStream fout = null;
    try{
        fout = new FileOutputStream(filePath, true);
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
        oos.writeObject(theDeck);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        if(oos  != null){
            oos.close();
        } 
    }
}

private FlashCardDeck[] loadDeck(){
    user.setDeckMade(true);
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        this.theDeck = (FlashCardDeck[])in.readObject();
        in.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return theDeck;
}
```

The error I'm getting is on the load method:

`java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: myPackage.UserInterface`

Saving works fine; I've opened up the .ser file after the SaveDeck method has executed and everything seemed to check out properly.

My question is if the problem is with the file itself, the save method, or external methods? I have made sure that everything not serializable (Namely, the Scanner class) is transient.

```
package myPackage.FlashCards;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class FlashCardDeck implements Serializable{


private static final long serialVersionUID = -1176413113990886560L;
public FlashCard[] theDeck;
public String deckName;


public FlashCardDeck(int cards, String name) {
    this.deckName = name;
    theDeck = new FlashCard[cards];
    for (int i = 0; i < theDeck.length; i++) {
        theDeck[i] = new FlashCard(i);
    }
}

public String getQuestion(int i) {
    return theDeck[i].QuestionToString();
}

public String getAnswer(int i ) {
    return theDeck[i].AnswerToString();
}

public String getName() {
    return deckName;
}

public int getDeckSize() {
    return theDeck.length;
}


}


package myPackage.FlashCards;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class FlashCard implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = -8880816241107858648L;

private transient Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

String question;
String answer;

public FlashCard(int i) {
    setCard(i);
}

public void setCard(int cards) {
    System.out.println("What is the question for number " + (cards + 1) + "?");
    question = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What is the answer for number " + (cards + 1) + "?");
    answer = in.nextLine();

}

public String QuestionToString() {
    return "Question: " + question;
}

public String AnswerToString() {
    return "Answer: " + answer;
}




}


package myPackage.FlashCards;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class UserInterface implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 7755668511730129821L;
private int moreThanOnce = 0;
boolean deckMade = false;

private transient Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

public int AmountOfDecks() {
    int decks;
    System.out.println("How many decks will you be creating? (Type the number, 
            not the word. Ex: 2)");
    decks = in.nextInt();
    while (decks <= 0) {
        System.out.println("You can't have less than one deck! Try again.");
        decks = in.nextInt();
    }
    return decks;
}


public int StartMenu() {
    int choice = 0;
    moreThanOnce++;
    if (moreThanOnce > 1) {
        choice = SecondMenu();
    } else {

        System.out.println("\nFlash Card Creation Engine Ver. 2.5 ALPHA");
        System.out.println("Press the cooresponding number for your 
                    choice.");
        System.out.println("1. Make a deck of flash cards");
        System.out.println("2. Play flash cards");
        System.out.println("3. Quit \n");

        try { choice = in.nextInt(); } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {}
    }

    return choice;
}

public int AmountOfCards(int cards) {
    int catchMe;
    deckMade = true;
    System.out.println("How many cards would you like? (Type the number, not the 
            word. Ex: 2)");
    try {
        catchMe = in.nextInt();
        while (catchMe <= 0) {
            System.out.println("You can't have less than one card! Try 
                            again!");
            catchMe = in.nextInt();
        }
    } catch (Exception ime) {
        System.out.println("Uh-oh, you did that wrong! Let's try that again. 
                    Try typing: 3");
        cards = 0;
        catchMe = in.nextInt();
    }

    cards = catchMe;
    return cards;
}

public boolean getDeckMade() {
    return deckMade;
}

public void setDeckMade(boolean makeDeckMade) {
    this.deckMade = makeDeckMade;
}

public String NameOfDeck() {
    String name;
    System.out.println("What would you like to name this deck?");
    name = in.next();
    return name;
}

private int SecondMenu() {
    int choice = 0;
    System.out.println("Now what would you like to do?");
    if (deckMade) {
        System.out.println("1. Make or load a deck of flash cards -- DONE");
    } else {
        System.out.println("1. Make a deck of flash cards.");
    }
    System.out.println("2. Play flash cards");
    System.out.println("3. Quit \n");

    try { choice = in.nextInt(); } catch (InputMismatchException ime)  {}
    return choice;
}

public boolean SetMode() {
    boolean timed = false;
    int userChoice = 0;
    while (userChoice < 1 || userChoice > 2) {
        System.out.println("What mode are you selecting?");
        System.out.println("1. Timed");
        System.out.println("2. Normal");
        System.out.println("3. Help");
        System.out.println("4. Quit");
        userChoice = in.nextInt();
        if (userChoice == 1) {
            timed = true;
        } else if (userChoice == 3) {
            System.out.println("Timed: Answers to a flash card will 
                            appear after a set amount of seconds, then show the next  
                            question after the same amount of seconds, which are set by 
                            the user (that's you!)");
            System.out.println("Normal: Answers to a flash card will 
                            appear when the user (also you!) presses enter, and wait for 
                            enter to be pressed before showing the next question.");
        } else if (userChoice == 4) {
            System.out.println("Have a good day.");
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Choose from the proivded list -- 1 for 
                            Timed mode, 2 for Normal mode, 3 to show the Help menu, 4 to 
                            quit.");
            System.out.println();

        }
    }

    return timed;
}

public String setQuestion(int cards) {
    String question = "";

    return question;

}

public String setAnswer(int cards) {
    String answer = "";
    return answer;
}


}
```

Comment: And what does the `FlashCardDeck` class look like?

Comment: can you paste the full class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class you're trying to serialize (and any non-transient objects referenced by that class) must implement the Serializable interface.

judging by the error you have a UserInterface class referenced there which is not serializable.

Edit:

Also

```
new FileOutputStream(filePath, true);
```

always appends to the end of the file instead of clearing the file. You may have older data in the file that is not deserialized correctly. You could try removing the file and trying again.

In general - appending different objects to a file may be a bad choice considering data corruption. If different files for each deck are not an option, I might go for a separate DeckStore object that holds all the decks and gets serialized as a whole.

Comment: UserInterface has implemented Serializable, with a serialVersionUID.

Comment: Only after you fixed it. The stream that you created before you fixed it is still corrupt, and you still have to recreate it with a valid version of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Class that you want to serialize should implement Serializable interface

```
public class FlashCardDeck implements Serializable {

    // Fields and methods of the class ...
}
```

The serialization interface has no methods or fields and serves only to identify the semantics of being serializable.

Comment: It does, I also have serialVersionUID for the class.

Comment: Than maybe you have reference/field in you FlashCardDeck class that is not implementing Serializable. Probably it is UserInterface class?